# sqldf LIKE operator for cyrillic words

Tags: r, sql-like, cyrillic, sqldf

I have a table - data.frame in UTF-8:

```
id|city
 1|Moscow
 2|London
 3|Москва
```

Row 3 is a Russian name for a city
I'm using `sqldf` library:

```
sqldf("select * from table_name where city like '%Moscow%'")
```

It's OK (returns 1st row)

```
sqldf("select * from table_name where city like '%Москва%'")
```

It returns 0 rows
Why? How solve this problem?

Comment: This seems to work for me, but I'm thinking it could be a locale issue.

Comment: Did you get an answer? when I used sqldf("SELECT UrlInclude FROM criteria where UrlInclude <> ''") I get '/bank/personal/loan' as a result, but when sqldf("SELECT Page FROM dataEASun where Page like ''+(SELECT UrlInclude FROM criteria where UrlInclude <> '')+'%'") I get 0 result. Also, when I directly subsitute value I get right result viz. sqldf("SELECT Page FROM dataEASun where Page like '/bank/personal/loan%'")